# strongloop Database discovery API for sql server giving same table name for primary and foreign Table name

Tags: api, foreign-key-relationship, strongloop, loopback

`discoverForeignKeys` and `discoverExportedForeignKeys` both are giving same table name for both `primary` and `foreign key` table

Comment: And do you have a question?

Comment: Yes. It was the issue I faced 2 days back and today I resolved the same and submitted on git as well. Reference for Others :-                                                        [https://github.com/savsharma2/loopback-sql-create-model-with-relation](https://github.com/savsharma2/loopback-sql-create-model-with-relation)

Comment: So this question is resolved and can be closed as such?

Comment: yes it can be closed but i had to change it in the strong loop api to get it done.